# Unity can not cast GameObject to my object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am writing a simple board game using unity.
I need to set a property of my object (Player), although I have a reference to it as a GameObject. I need to cast, but cant. 
Here is what i have tried

```
public GameObject PlayerPrefab;

private GameObject player;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    if (!isLocalPlayer)
    {
        return;
    }
    Debug.Log("Spawning.");
    CmdSpawn();
}


[Command]
void CmdSpawn()
{
    player = Instantiate(PlayerPrefab);
    ((Player)player).parentNetId = this.netId;
    NetworkServer.SpawnWithClientAuthority(player, connectionToClient);
}
```

I have the following error:
"Assets/Scripts/PlayerConnectionObject.cs(27,18): error CS0030: Cannot convert type `UnityEngine.GameObject' to`Player'"

Comment: What is `(Player)player` supposed to do? of what type is `Player`? Do you mean `player.GetComponent<Player>()`?

Comment: U should understand that 'Player' is a class written by me : )

Comment: But a class of what type? You should understand that it wont be possible to simply typecast `GameObject` to `Player` if they don't inherit from each other or a common ancestor class...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Player is the component that attached to your PlayerPrefab
You should use GetComponent<>.
Also use can store cached PlayerComponent cause of how slow does GetComponent work:

Change field:

```
private Player player;
```

And inside command:

```
player = Instantiate(PlayerPrefab).GetComponent<Player>();
player.parentNetId = this.netId;
NetworkServer.SpawnWithClientAuthority(player.gameObject, connectionToClient);
```